# Find if Column Belongs to User Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to compute the number of columns with not null constraint in my database. So I thought about querying the table sys.all_columns:
`select * from sys.all_columns`

The problem is that it provides me with extra information I dont need (columns in system defined tables).

So I have to add some **SQL code to determine whether some column belongs to User Defined Table or not**. What is the best way to proceed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do an inner join between `sys.columns` and `sys.tables`.  The latter table is the catalog view for user tables, so joining on `object_id` should give you the corresponding columns:

```
select c.*
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t
on c.object_id = t.object_id;
```

Taking this a step further on what seems to be your end result, if you want to get all nullable columns in user tables, this quick query should work:

```
select
    object_name = 
        quotename(s.name) + 
        '.' + 
        quotename(t.name),
    column_name = quotename(c.name),
    c.is_nullable
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t
on c.object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.schemas s
on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where c.is_nullable = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr @Thomas Stringer ! This is perfectly what I'm looking for !!

Comment: [Or instead of using `schema_name()` just join to `sys.schemas` too (just blogged about this today)](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions/) :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Excellent article, and I've made those changes.  Great read and I'll definitely refine my ways as well!  Thanks!